# What is the best way to display menu in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1, middleware

I would like to ask that which is the best way to show menu with access parameters.

So, now I'm using the following code in my `default.blade.php`:

```
@if (Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('something'))
    <li class="{{ (Request::is('panda/something') ? 'open' : '') }}">
        <a href="{{ URL::to('panda/flot_charts') }}" class="menu-dropdown">
             <span class="menu-text">Menu 1</span><i class="menu-expand"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
        @if (Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('school'))
            <li class="{{ (Request::is('panda/school') ? "active" : '') }}">
                 <a href="{{ route('school') }}"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-cogs"></i><span class="menu-text">Submenu</span></a>
            </li>
        @endif
        </ul>
    </li>
@endif
```

It looks like:
[image: screenshot about left menu bar]

I know that this solution is not really good. I'm looking for an easier and more simple way to show menu.

I always have to check what page the visitor sees and the same menu has to be active.

Now I'm using [Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1), but I'd like to use [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) in the future.

Shall I store the menu parameters in `db`?

Thanks for your help!

Peter

Comment: Why do you thing this is wrong? Also, middleware classes here do not take too much difference, because they meant to filter http requests.

Comment: This code works, but I hope there is a more simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Sentinel` which is the updated version of `Sentry` and is also open source. Here's what I use for my authentication middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Auth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($user = Sentinel::check()) {
            if ($user->hasAccess(Route::currentRouteAction())) {
                view()->share('user', $user);
            } else {
                return view('errors.forbidden');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then your menu code could be changed to:

```
@if ($user->hasAccess('something'))
    <li class="{{ (Request::is('panda/something') ? 'open' : '') }}">
        <a href="{{ URL::to('panda/flot_charts') }}" class="menu-dropdown">
             <span class="menu-text">Menu 1</span><i class="menu-expand"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
        @if ($user->hasAccess('school'))
            <li class="{{ (Request::is('panda/school') ? "active" : '') }}">
                 <a href="{{ route('school') }}"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-cogs"></i><span class="menu-text">Submenu</span></a>
            </li>
        @endif
        </ul>
    </li>
@endif
```

This is only a slight change, though. You might want to check out [Caffeinated Menus](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/caffeinated/menus) which appears to be the most popular of [the package for Laravel 5.1 menu creation on Packalyst](http://packalyst.com/packages/tag/menu).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I will try Sentinel and Caffeinated Menus:)